# Convergence to non-degenerate limit.

Tags: asymptotics

If $X_1,X_2......$ follow Poisson$(λ)$. Can we find suitable constants $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $a_n(Y_n - b_n)$ converges to a non degenerate limit where $Y_n = (1 - \frac{1}{n})^{n\bar{X}_n}$.

I have shown that $Y_n\rightarrow e^{-\lambda}$ almost surely. However I cant find $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that the desired limit will be a non-degenerate distribution.

Comment: What if you consider the same problem with $Y_n = e^{-\overline{X}_n}$?  Maybe if you can come up with constants for that, they may work in the original problem as well.

Comment: I'd try to show that variance of $Y_n$ decreases as $1/n$, and hence $a_n = 1/\sqrt{n}$, $b_n = e^{-\lambda}$ (or $b_n = (1-1/n)^{n\lambda}$ should work.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4107774/321264