# Problem in convergence in probability involving Poisson distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be identically distributed and independent random variables. If distribution of $X_1$ is Poisson($\lambda$).

Let $\bar{X_n} =\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_n}{n}$ and $Y_n=(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n\bar{X_n}}$

Find suitable sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $a_n(Y_n-b_n)$ converges to non-degenerated distribution (i.e converges to a random variable whose distribution, having the distribution of constant random variable).

My attempt: I have tried to find a continuous function $f$ such that $Y_n = f(\bar{X_n})$ and then use continuous mapping theorem. But I couldn't find such a function. I think the solution will use central limit theorem and continuous mapping theorem but I can't figure out how.

Comment: entrance exam to phd programme?

Comment: 'non-degenerated distribution (i.e converges to a random variable whose distribution, having the distribution of constant random variable).' --> wait NON-DEGENERATE? or DEGENERATE?

Comment: but anyhoo it looks like to do with $e := \lim (1+\frac1n)^n$

Comment: @BCLC it's entrance for a phd programme. I checked it again, it's non-degenerate.

Comment: Aierel nice. good luck. wait... degenerate is the one that means constant/almost surely constant random variable's distribution? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution

Comment: @Aierel I've added a proof that  $\sqrt n (Y_n - e^{- \lambda})$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal N(0,\lambda e^{\lambda})$.

Comment: btw this is convergence surely? almost surely? in probability? in distribution?

Comment: @BCLC it's convergence in distribution.

Comment: oh right yeah. yeah.

Comment: wait so DEGENERATE? or NON-DEGENERATE? @GabrielRomon and Aierel

Comment: @BCLC I'd say an a.s. constant random variable is degenerate, whereas $\mathcal N(0,\ast)$ is non-degenerate.

Comment: @GabrielRomon which is WHY i find op to be unclear 'non-degenerated distribution (i.e converges to a random variable whose distribution, having the distribution of constant random variable).' are you confused by OP? or not confused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\ln Y_n = -\bar X_n\frac{\ln(1-\frac 1n)}{-\frac 1n}.$$

By the SLLN, $\bar X_n$ converges a.s. to $\lambda$, and $\frac{\ln(1-\frac 1n)}{-\frac 1n}$ converges deterministically to $1$, thus $\ln Y_n$ converges a.s. to $-\lambda$.

By the continuous mapping theorem, $Y_n$ converges a.s. to $e^{-\lambda}$, hence $Y_n-e^{-\lambda}$ converges a.s. to $0$.

---

Note that $$\sqrt n (\ln Y_n + \lambda) 
= -\sqrt n (\bar X_n - \lambda) - \bar X_n\sqrt n \left(\frac{\ln(1-\frac 1n)}{-\frac 1n}-1 \right)
= -\sqrt n (\bar X_n - \lambda) - \bar X_n(\frac 1{2\sqrt n} + o(\frac 1{\sqrt n}))$$

The second summand $-\bar X_n(\frac 1{2\sqrt n} + o(\frac 1{\sqrt n}))$ converges a.s to $0$, while by the CLT $-\sqrt n (\bar X_n - \lambda)$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal N(0,\lambda)$.

By Slutsky's theorem, $\sqrt n (\ln Y_n - (- \lambda))$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal N(0,\lambda)$.

By the Delta method, $\sqrt n (Y_n - e^{- \lambda})$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal N(0,\lambda e^{\lambda})$.

Comment: is it that OP means to say degenerate instead of non-degenerate because this is easy for non-degenerate?

Comment: @BCLC I've added a proof  that $\sqrt n (Y_n - e^{- \lambda})$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal N(0,\lambda e^{\lambda})$.

Comment: Gabriel Romon so you're answering in case of degen and in case of non-degen?

Comment: @BCLC $Y_n$ converges a.s. to $e^{-\lambda}$, and the statement $\sqrt n (Y_n - e^{- \lambda}) \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal N(0,\lambda e^{\lambda})$ says something about the rate of convergence to $0$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Thanks a lot for the answer. I was think of proving : if a sequence or real numbers $a_n $ converging to $a \neq 0$ and random variables $T_n$ converging in distribution to $T$, then $a_n^{T_n}$ converges to $a^{T}$. Now I know how to do it